# raster to vector python gdal

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I am trying to convert a raster file to polygon shp, but when I do, the values in shp came out as integer, although I want the values to be float and equal to the values in my raster.

the code used was as the one below:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
import os

sourceRaster = gdal.Open('raster.tif')
band = sourceRaster.GetRasterBand(0)
bandArray = band.ReadAsArray()
outShapefile = "polygonized"
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
if os.path.exists(outShapefile+".shp"):
    driver.DeleteDataSource(outShapefile+".shp")
outDatasource = driver.CreateDataSource(outShapefile+ ".shp")
outLayer = outDatasource.CreateLayer("polygonized", srs=None)
newField= ogr.FieldDefn('VALUE')
outLayer.CreateField(newField)
gdal.Polygonize( band, None, outLayer, -1, [], callback=None )
outDatasource.Destroy()
sourceRaster = None
```

let me know what am I doing wrong
thanks

Comment: There are answers to your question in: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67956/raster-values-become-integer-when-polygonizing/403966 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/128139/how-to-convert-float-raster-to-vector-with-python-gdal